# Mail won't send

Tags: php, email

I have this script:

```
$to      = $_GET["to"];
$subject = $_GET["sub"];
$message = $_GET["message"];
$from    = "admin@chipperyman573.com";
$headers = "From:" . $_GET["from"];
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I go to:

```
http://chipperyman573.com/THEURL?to=myemail@gmail.com&sub=Subject&message=Hi&from=admin@chipperyman573.com
```

I want to always send it from `admin@chipperyman573.com`, however if I want to change the first part (say, to `personal@chipperyman573.com`) it won't send. I want to use `admin@chipperyman573.com`.

(admin@chipperyman573.com is the only one that exists).

Comment: I am just going to point out that you really need some security on this, or it's all too easy for anyone to send emails from your address.

Comment: Can you send ANY mail from the PHP server? It is a common misconception, that the `mail()` function in PHP will "just work" - e.g. you need a running MTA.

Comment: It's password protected, in able to access it you have to get past [this](http://puu.sh/3mQta.png)

Comment: @EugenRieck Can you define "MTA"? Sorry, I'm new...

Comment: First of all: Can you send ANY mail from the PHP server?

Comment: Using the CPanel thing, yes.

Comment: OK - let me rephrase: Does the use of the `mail()` function in PHP work normally, but not in this script, or does it never work.

Comment: It worked on my old host however I switched. I was using a slightly different code however for the most part it was the same (There was no $_GET for the from, it was just a static string). I'll try it now... **EDIT** Okay, I can send with a static "From" header.

Comment: Well, in fact I was talking about **this** server, not some other.

Comment: I want to enter it with the URL.

Comment: first try to use the static value  for to mail and other after that you able to check where is error